# Replacing set of rows with another set in sqlite

Tags: sql, sqlite

I've a table `values` with columns like this:

```
id:       integer primary key
value:    varchar(128)
type_id:  integer (foreign key)
owner_id: integer (foreign key)
```

and some sample data:

```
id     value  type_id  owner_id
...
5      aaa    0        1
6      bbb    0        2             // Rows
7      ccc    1        2             // to
8      ddd    1        2             // be
9      eee    2        2             // replaced
10     fff    0        3
...
```

Now I would like to replace all rows where `owner_id` == 2 with a new set of data. Simple approach is to `DELETE` all rows  for `owner_id` == 2 and `INSERT` new ones. However I wonder if there is another solution?

In my case:

- New set may contain exactly the same data (no action needed).
- Or it could contain the same data but one row (deletion needed). Example: no more `bbb` with `type_id` == 0
- Or there is one more row (insertion needed). Example: `bbb`, `ccc`, `ddd` and `eee` with exactly the same values for `type_id`  plus `ggg` with `type_id` = 1
- Or one of the values in `values` column changed (update needed). Example: exactly the same data but instead of `ccc` with `type_id` == 1 there is `ggg` with `type_id` == 1
- It can be also any combination of operations above.

The reason I try to avoid `DELETE` + `INSERT` that I'll have many such updates and with such approach `id` will start growing fast.

Comment: You do know there is an `UPDATE` command in SQLite too, right?

Comment: @MPelletier: sure, however what I need is to smart solution which would find out differences between what's in database and what I want to place there and then would remove what doesn't exist in new set, changed what changed and insert what's new. Or maybe I can achieve this with `UPDATE`?

Comment: I don't know that such a thing exists, that it would *guess* based on *your* data rules what to erase, what to update, and what to insert, without you programming that. One trick you can use is `INSERT OR REPLACE` which will insert if the primary key value is not found, but replace if it is, so it acts like an update.

Comment: @MPelletier: ok, that's fine too, at least I won't write something already written ;). Thank you.

Comment: (i) Do you have the data to be merged into your **values** table in another table? (ii) How is the merge by **owner_id** initiated? Could/should there be multiple `DELETE`s, `INSERT`s or/and `UPDATE`s in parallel? (iii) Does solely the combination of **owner_id** and **type_id** drive, whether `DELETE`s, `INSERT`s or `UPDATE`s are necessary? (iv) How exactly is the second item in your list to be read? For **owner_id** 2 and **type_id** 1, your table does not hold **value** "bbb".

Comment: (v) For **owner_id** 2 and **type_id** 1, your table does actually hold two values. Is the combination of **owner_id** and **type_id** really not unique? If so: How to decide between `UPDATE` and `INSERT`?

Comment: @Abecee: (i) I don't, but if it simplifies this case, I can add them. (ii) Anything can happen - I've set of values in db and a new set comes. Data should be replaced. (iii). All new data will be related to particular `owner_id`, but I is unknow if we will get the same `value`s or `type_id`. (iv) fat finger error. there should be `bbb` with `type_id`==0

Comment: @Abecee: (v) yes it is possible that there will be multiple `value`s with the same `type_id` within one `owner_id`. When there is such a dillema, `UPDATE` will be fine until we end up with valid result. When I think of it longer, the algorithm may work this way: compare set's sizes. If there are more rows for particular `owner_id` than we want - delete rows from db and then `UPDATE` others so the `value`s and `type_id`s are as we want. Otherwise (less in db than in a new set) also call `UPDATE` on existing rows and then `INSERT` missing ones.

Comment: (i) Could a particular change set hold more than one **type_id** for a specific **owner_id**? If so and the same is true for the **values** table - how to proceed in all the possible cases? (More/less combinations in the change set than in **values**?) (ii) If there are multiple values for an **owner_id** & **type_id** in **values**, but only one in the change set - which **id** to preserve?

Comment: (i) Yes it is possible. Frankly speaking I've solved my case on client's side by calling `UPDATE` and overriding all existing rows then I `DELETE` if there are more in db or `INSERT` if I want to add more.

Answer (score 1):

As you don't seem to be around to respond to comments, let's get started.
In line with my above comments, I did iron out (what appears to me as) some wrinkles:

- in your request: "no more bbb with type_id == 1" - which is not part of your sample data - going for **type_id** 0), and
- your sample data: (**value**s "ccc" *and* "ddd" for **type_id** 1 and **owner_id** - going for unique **owner_id** **type_id** combinations).
  If applicable, you might enforce the latter by:
  `CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ValuesTable_TypeOwner ON ValuesTable(owner_id, type_id);`

NB: I changed the tablename as **VALUES** is a SQL reserved word.

You might want to try along (pulling the to be applied modifications from a table called **Changes**):

### Delete no longer existing **owner_id** **type_id** combinations:

```
WITH
To_Delete (id) AS (
  SELECT
    id
  FROM ValuesTable V
  JOIN Changes C
    ON V.owner_id = C.owner_id
    AND V.type_id
        NOT IN (SELECT type_id
                FROM Changes
                WHERE owner_id = C.owner_id)
)
DELETE FROM ValuesTable
WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM To_Delete)
;
```

### Update deviating values:

```
WITH
To_Update (id) AS (
  SELECT
    id
  FROM ValuesTable V
  JOIN Changes C
    ON V.owner_id = C.owner_id
    AND V.type_id = C.type_id
    AND V.value <> C.value
)
UPDATE ValuesTable
SET value = (SELECT value
             FROM Changes
             WHERE ValuesTable.owner_id = owner_id
                   AND ValuesTable.type_id = type_id
            )
WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM To_Update)
;
```

### Insert new owner_id type_id combinations:

```
WITH
To_Insert (value, type_id, owner_id) AS (
  SELECT
    value
    , type_id
    , owner_id
  FROM Changes
  WHERE NOT EXISTS
        (SELECT 1
         FROM ValuesTable
         WHERE Changes.owner_id = owner_id
         AND Changes.type_id = type_id
        )
)
INSERT INTO ValuesTable (value, type_id, owner_id)
SELECT value, type_id, owner_id FROM To_Insert
;
```

Starting from

```
ValuesTable                             Changes
| id | value | type_id | owner_id |    | value | type_id | owner_id |
|----|-------|---------|----------|    |-------|---------|----------|
|  5 |   aaa |       0 |        1 |    |   ccc |       1 |        2 |
|  6 |   bbb |       0 |        2 |    |   ddd |       2 |        2 |
|  7 |   ccc |       1 |        2 |    |   xxx |       3 |        2 |
|  8 |   ddd |       2 |        2 |    |   yyy |       4 |        2 |
|  9 |   eee |       3 |        2 |    
| 10 |   fff |       0 |        3 |
```

it returns:

```
| id | value | type_id | owner_id |
|----|-------|---------|----------|
|  5 |   aaa |       0 |        1 |
|  7 |   ccc |       1 |        2 |
|  8 |   ddd |       2 |        2 |
|  9 |   xxx |       3 |        2 |
| 11 |   yyy |       4 |        2 |
| 10 |   fff |       0 |        3 |
```

See it in action: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/f87cb/1).

NB: Instead of using a **Changes** table, the `WITH` clause could, of course, be extended accordingly.

Please comment if and as this requires adjustment / further detail.

Comment: I've answered your questions in comments

Comment: @MichałWalenciak: (i) Is it correct to say, all your requirements are met except for possibly multiple values for some **owner_id** **type_id** combination(s)? If not, please, provide sample input (for both **ValuesTable** and **Change**), and the expected result. - Feel free to provide multiple sets to cover corner cases. (SQL Fiddle much appreciated.) (ii) Do you want such cases to be addressed (a) whenever the suite of statements is executed, or (b) when the respective **owner_id**(s) is/are in the current **Change** set? (iii) Is there always just a single **owner_id** in **Change**?